# Bugreport location

Tags: debug

If I have bug reports enabled in dev options and I take a bugreport from the power button menu, where are these reports saved?

I see there is an option to share it, but I want to pull it directly through adb for analysis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bugreports are stored in `/data/data/com.android.shell/files/bugreports`.

You can't access the file directly without root access.

Comment: On Android 6 (at least on Samsung Galaxy J5) is `/data/data/com.android.shell/files/bugreports` accessible also for `shell` user.

Answer (score 10):

As of Android 10, at least for Pixel devices, bugreports taken from the device are available in `/bugreports` - **even without root access!** You can get the names of the available bug reports with

```
adb shell ls /bugreports/
```

then get the file you want with `adb pull`, e.g.

```
adb pull /bugreports/bugreport-foobar-lotsofnumbers-date.zip
```

Comment: It worked for me on my Galaxy Note 9 but my bugreports were in `/bugreports/bugreport/`

Comment: Officially documented at [Capture and read bug reports - Save an older bug report](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report#bugreportadbpull)

Comment: If you don't have adb set up, it is available in the Android Studio Device File Explorer. Just open the top level shortcut to the directory `bugreports`

Answer (score 5):

In my case, they are in `/data/user_de/0/com.android.shell/files/bugreports/`

Comment: and linked as /bugreports

Answer (score 4):

You can connect your device to your PC, and use android SDK tools adb, then go to the directory and  in your command line use `adb shell bugreport > bugreport.txt` Your bugreport will output.

Comment: That will work for taking a new bugreport but not for retrieving one that already exists (i.e. taken while using the phone unattached to adb)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to view the bug reports on your PC,
run adb from a directory where you want to save the bugreports with

```
adb pull /data/data/com.android.shell/files/bugreports
```

But this may require `root` permission.

Comment: That has already been mentioned in [this answer](/a/125721/16575) – apart from the `adb pull` part. When using `adb`, on the device's end it's usually running as `shell` user – which IMHO is the owner of that location, so no root should be needed to pull the files.